# Calculate a measure based on previous row in PowerBi Dax

Tags: recursion, powerbi, dax

I am creating some what-if analysis in Power BI, which involves several created parameters, allowing the users to alter inputs in order to create graphs and financial estimates / outputs.

I would like to achieve the following output in DAX, where Net Incoming is a result of selected parameters, Gains 1 and Gains 2 are in month calculations based on the previous end of month results against some flat rate, and the end of current month is the summation of these.

| Months | Net Incoming | Gains 1 | Gains 2 | Start_of_month | End_of_month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 25,000 | 0 | 0 | - | 25,000 |
| 1 | 240 | 86.46 | 10.42 | 25,000 | 25,337 |
| 2 | 252 | 87.62 | 10.56 | 25,337 | 25,687 |
| 3 | 268 | 88.83 | 10.70 | 25,687 | 26,055 |
| 4 | 235 | 90.11 | 10.86 | 26,055 | 26,391 |
| 5 | 237 | 91.27 | 11.00 | 26,391 | 26,730 |
| 6 | 253 | 92.44 | 11.14 | 26,730 | 27,086 |
| 7 | 223 | 93.67 | 11.29 | 27,086 | 27,414 |
| 8 | 298 | 94.81 | 11.42 | 27,414 | 27,819 |
| 9 | 212 | 96.21 | 11.59 | 27,819 | 28,138 |
| 10 | 263 | 97.31 | 11.72 | 28,138 | 28,510 |
| 11 | 262 | 98.60 | 11.88 | 28,510 | 28,883 |
| 12 | 223 | 99.89 | 12.03 | 28,883 | 29,218 |

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNceI.png)

Hence this is a recursive function which can be summarised as

```
N_end_of_month  =   (Previous End_of_month) + (Previous End_of_month * (Base_Rate / 12) ) + (Previous End_of_month * (Bonus_Rate / 12) ) + Net Incoming
```

I've seen some examples of creating recursive functions in Power Query - however I don't believe I can pull the parameters used in the dashboard through in order to use them. Perhaps there is some way to solve this function for N and hence not require recursion? Otherwise how can I introduce this simple recursive example into DAX?

Comment: Dax isn't recursive. Sometimes you can find an iterative solution/formula that will give the same result. If you can update your question with more detail on what your input data is and what the desired result should be, then we can help. It is unclear what the table is above, and your code doesn't seem to reference columns in the table, or are referencing values from other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how the above can be achieved with iterative functions to calculate compound interest with addition net coming in, with two rates.

**Set-up**
Initial table for example called `WhatIf`:

| Months | Net Incoming |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 25,000 |
| 1 | 240 |
| 2 | 252 |
| 3 | 268 |
| 4 | 235 |
| 5 | 237 |
| 6 | 253 |
| 7 | 223 |
| 8 | 298 |
| 9 | 212 |
| 10 | 263 |
| 11 | 262 |
| 12 | 223 |

Two rates defined in measures (these can come from anywhere):

```
Rate Base = 0.0415

Rate Bonus = 0.005
```

**New measures needed to produce the desired table in the question**

This is the main measure, it works by using compound interest formula per month net incoming, with **both** rates added together.

```
End of Month = 
  var rate = DIVIDE([Rate Base] + [Rate Bonus], 12)
  var thisMonth = MAX(WhatIf[Months])
  var prevMonths = FILTER(ALL(WhatIf[Months]), WhatIf[Months] < thisMonth )
  var prevNet = ADDCOLUMNS(
    prevMonths,
    "netAmt", CALCULATE(SUM(WhatIf[Net Incoming]))
  )
  var result = 
    SUMX(
      prevNet,
        (
          var netMonth = thisMonth - 'WhatIf'[Months]
          var netAmt = [netAmt]
          return netAmt * (1 + rate)^netMonth
        )
    )

  return result + MIN(WhatIf[Net Incoming])
```

With the above main measure, the rest are fairly simple:

```
Start of Month = 
  var thisMonth = MAX(WhatIf[Months])
  return [End of Month](WhatIf[Months] = thisMonth - 1)


Gains 1 = 
  var gain = [End of Month] - [Start of Month] - MIN(WhatIf[Net Incoming])
  var gainRatio = DIVIDE([Rate Base], [Rate Base] + [Rate Bonus])
  return gain * gainRatio


Gains 2 = 
  var gain = [End of Month] - [Start of Month] - MIN(WhatIf[Net Incoming])
  var gainRatio = DIVIDE([Rate Bonus], [Rate Base] + [Rate Bonus])
  return gain * gainRatio
```

**Result**

[image]